# Highcharts Formatting Axes, Labels & Tooltips

Tags: highcharts, formatting, decimal, prefix, suffix

I'm evaluating Highcharts and I'm struggling to format my axes and data labels correctly. On the tooltip object for a series I can set the prefix, suffix and decimals ( this is wonderful ). I cannot find similar options for data labels and the axes?

What is the correct way to format the axis, tooltips and labels to all use the correct prefix, suffix, decimals and use a comma for the thousands separator? Is there a single place this can be set to be inherited?

I have tried using a formatter on data labels but I've been unable to implement it as it does not know what "this" is.

Below is my example using a new angular 14 project:

Thank you

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SeriesColumnOptions, SeriesLineOptions } from 'highcharts';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-format',
  template: '<highcharts-chart [Highcharts]="Highcharts" [options]="options" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; display: block;"></highcharts-chart>'
})
export class FormatComponent implements OnInit {

  Highcharts = Highcharts;
  options!: Highcharts.Options;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.options = {
      title: {
        text: ''
      },
      xAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'xAxis'
        },
        categories: ['Cat A', 'Cat B', 'Cat C', 'Cat D', 'Cat E']
      },
      yAxis: [
        {
          title: {
            text: 'currency axis'
          }
        },
        {
          title: {
            text: 'percent axis'
          },
          opposite: true
        }
      ],
      series: []
    };

    const currencySeries: SeriesColumnOptions = {
      type: 'column',
      name: 'Currency',
      data: [123.45, 4324.12, 17245.23, 123.5, 13453.4],
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      },
      tooltip: {
        valuePrefix: '£',
        valueDecimals: 2
      }
    };
    this.options.series?.push(currencySeries);

    const percentSeries: SeriesLineOptions = {
      type: 'line',
      name: 'Percent',
      data: [34.1, 62, 82.3, 76.6, 12.3, 99],
      yAxis: 1,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      },
      tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '%',
        valueDecimals: 1
      }
    };
    this.options.series?.push(percentSeries);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To format axis labels check [xAxis.labels.format](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.format), datalabels units or custom formating you can set in [dataLabels.format](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.dataLabels.format), also recomended options is use callback [formatter()](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter).

"This" depending on where it is called, refers to an axis or a series.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  xAxis: {
    labels: {
      formatter: function() {
        let label = this.axis.defaultLabelFormatter.call(this);
        console.log('xAxis this:', this);
        return label;
      }
    }
  },

  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, ],
    pointStart: 9000,
    type: 'column',
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      formatter: function() {
        console.log('datalabels this:', this);
        return this.y;
      }
    }
  }]

});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vam2t5hw/

Comment: Thank you, I had tried that but was getting an error, but turns out it does compile okay.

TSLint: Expected method shorthand in object literal ('{formatter() {...}}'). (object-literal-shorthand)

Is there a similar formatter to call for the tooltip per series?

Comment: Yes, you can invoke a tooltip for specific series, try [tooltip.pointFormatter](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.tooltip.pointFormatter), in this case for line https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6sy7p3xa/1/.